# Why Does Relative Magnitude of AC Current Waveform Decrease Based on Phase Ange?

Tags: power, ac, current-measurement, triac

**Background**

First off, I apologize if this is comparatively basic theory.  My primary profession is firmware and I only do electronics as a hobby.

I am attempting to design a power supply for a ~450W resistive heating element.  The circuit is pretty basic and uses a microcontroller, optoisolator and a triac to control the load.  This is working as expected but, now, I am attempting to read the current.  This is done using an external sensing IC (ACS71020) which is giving strange results.  This question, however, is not about the ACS (it will get its own question once I understand the general question asked here).

**The Setup**

In an attempt to understand how current flows through this device I have created the following (simplified) test setup:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff64Qj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where:

- XFMR1 is a 1:166 current transformer
- SCOPE is my oscilloscope (Siglent SDS1104X-E)
- DMM is a Fluke 77 for additional data
- TRIG is the optoisolated trigger signal from the MCU

**The Problem**

It seems like the amplitude of the current waveform is progressively more attenuated as the firing angle is reduced.  Consider the following graphs taken from my oscilloscope at different firing angles (as measured as a percentage of total output power).  Note that the yellow trace is the unmolested line voltage and the pink (purple?) trace is the measurement from the current transformer.

- 10%: [image: 10% power waveform]
- 50%: [image: 50% power waveform]
- 70%: [image: 70% power waveform]
- 90%: [image: 90% power waveform]
- 100%: [image: 100% power waveform]

Notice how the current waveform begins to diminish (relatively) as the power is increased.  In each of the waveforms above the scale is held constant.

**Questions**

1. What causes this behavior and is it expected?
2. My DMM measures a linear increase in RMS current; in order for this to be true shouldn't the waveform *NOT* diminish?
3. How does this not violate Ohm's law given that my controller already accounts for the area under the curve (eg. 30% power is 30% of the area under the curve; *not* 30% the distance from the zero cross point)?

---

**Edit 1:**

The load resistor was calculated by following [this](https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/node/156.html%20guide) guide.

- First, I calculated the max p-p secondary current: `5A max * 1.414 = 7.07A p-p * 1/166 = 0.0429A`.
- Then, I chose 4V RMS as max voltage based on [the datasheet](http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/CSE186L.pdf) for the current transformer I had on hand.  This was converted to p-p: `4 * 1.414 = 5.656V`
- Next, `Rload = V/I = 5.656 / 0.0429 = 132.8 Ohms`.
- The closest standard resistor I had handy was 110 Ohms.  Feeding this back in: `Vmax = 0.0429 * 110 = 4.685 * 0.707 = 3.312V`.  This is less than the 4VRMS max for the transformer so I should be good.

---

**Edit 2:**

For the DMM, below are the readings I get at various power outputs on the bulb:

[image: DMM current vs. power level]

As you can see, it is quite linear, which I would expect since my controller handles the integral for the area under the curve which corresponds to a given power.

Is this linear assumption incorrect?

Comment: Is the load really a lampbulb? That would explain it. As the bulb gets hotter, its resistance increases.

Comment: Yeah, it is actually a bulb.  I did notice a little bit of current variance as the filaments heated but I tried to wait for this to stabilize before taking my measurements.

Comment: And what about the DSO rms values VS. DMM values?

Comment: So this may be my ignorance here but I am not sure how to range in the DSO values w.r.t. the actual current.  I selected the load resistor such that the max voltage wouldn't exceed the current transformer's max.  Thus far I have just been looking at relative changes.

Comment: "I selected the load resistor such that the max voltage wouldn't exceed the current transformer's max", can you elaborate this?

Comment: Sure thing.  See Edit 1 in the question.

Comment: I once made a 8 channel “Chaser” with 10A Triacs controlled by a variable oscillator for my buddy Peter Allen’s band RAINTREE using fat Albert bulbs. it could also be controlled by a mic in the kick drum.  then the sound guy decided to run 5A stage lights and blew all the Triacs, because he failed to understand , metal  filaments have a cold resistance 8% of hot so when flashing at a 1Hz rate they were probably peaking around 30A and phhhttt.

Comment: Are you sure that your DMM is measuring "true rms"? Some cheaper meters assume that the waveform is a sinusoid and estimate the rms value from a measurement of the peak value. Since your current waveform is not a sinusoid one of the cheaper meters won't give accurate readings.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: I see.  Is 8% average for most filaments or is this something I will need to understand for the chemistry for the particular bulb I am using?  Though, I admit I am a little confused.  If the hot resistance is 12.5 times higher (1 / 0.08), shouldn't the current be 12.5 times lower?  It seems like my current waveform only halves; is part of this accounted for in voltage drop?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: I am pretty sure the DMM is good.  It is an old school Fluke 77 from circa 1990.  A close friend's father was a EE and, as he aged and couldn't pursue these hobbies, he give most of his kit to me.  This thing has been old dependable ever since.  It could be falling out of calibration but it has been bang on for mos other tasks.

Comment: recall Cold current is 12x hot current at bulb rated power meaning start power at the peak voltage (worst case) is 12x rated power, but on average I usually say 10x. Your current shunt has a bit leading phase.

Comment: Also, for those curious, I added the DMM readings in Edit 2.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: I see.  I re-read you response and I think I get it.  To restate to verify understanding: V = IR but bulb filaments have a variable R based on temperature.  As R goes up I must go down, which is what I see above.  The one part I don't yet fully understand is why V would go up?  Is the increase accounted for in *both* voltage an current?  And, if so, how is that "divided up" between the two.  If I understand the implication, my current is halving on the graphs above so the voltage across the bulb should be 6x rated in the fully activated state?

Comment: I don’t see your reference to last comment

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: I went back to try to edit it but couldn't after 5 minutes.  I ended up deleting it in an attempt to be more understandable.  Someone once said something about the best laid plans of mice and men...

Comment: Voltage is constant except for inductive glitch

Comment: @MysteryMoose I have a Fluke 77 myself and really like it, but it is not described as a "true RMS" meter. Fluke says that the AC measurements are "average responding".

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Ah damn.  I was hoping that mine, since it was so old, was true RMS and the new versions were suffering from the modern "Cheap Design Syndrome".  Unfortunately, both the data above and your statement refute that hope.  I also have a true RMS meter integrated into the board (ACS71020).  In a cosmic twist of irony, I created this question believing I was debugging an issue in that chip only to find out the opposite.  There is a life lesson in here somewhere about expectations...  Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: @MysteryMoose You did a really good job asking the question and thinking about your results. You should be proud that you had this great learning experience!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Thanks.  I don't want to trigger the extended discussion ban but, yeah, I did try to make as much progress on this before I asked for help.  Gotta meet the community at least half way, IMO.  Plus, I totally didn't expect this question would end with me hunting on Amazon for a new DMM.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian Drummond's comment about light bulb resistance increasing with temperature is (most of) the answer. The cold resistance of an incandescent light bulb filament is typically 10 times less than at its rated voltage. At low phase angle the power drawn by the bulb is less so it heats up less and draws *more* current than it would if its resistance remained the same at lower brightness.

If you want to control the power output accurately then you will have to measure the true [rms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) power by taking many instantaneous current and voltage readings and multiplying them, then sum and average the results over a full mains cycle. Any other method will only be an approximation that could be quite inaccurate at low phase angles.